# How to Create Custom Dropdown Field Component with Redux-Form V6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select, redux-form

I've got an app that will be form-heavy, and I'd like as much control as possible, while using as few dependencies as I can. To do so, I'd like to take advantage of redux-form v6's custom Field component API and make a bunch of custom components that I can drop in at will. One of these components is a drop down select.

The problem is the custom drop down component does not connect to state, even though it renders OK.

In the docs, the examples accomplish this like:

```
<Field name="favoriteColor" component="select">
  <option></option>
  <option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
  <option value="#00ff00">Green</option>
  <option value="#0000ff">Blue</option>
</Field>
```

I'm looking for a plug-and-play approach where I can drop in a component, and feed into the props an array of data:

**Form.js**:

```
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="dropDownSelect">Select an Option</label>
        <Field
          name="dropDownSelect"
          component={DropDownSelect}
          people={people}
          className="form-control"
        >
        </Field>
      </div>
```

**DropDownSelect.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './styles.css';

class DropDownSelect extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  renderSelectOptions = (person) => {
    return (
      <option key={person} value={person}>{person}</option>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        {this.props.people.map(this.renderSelectOptions)}
      </select>
    );
  }
}


export default DropDownSelect;
```

When I check Redux DevTools, the field's value never populates when interacting with the dropdown:

[image]

I picked a value for both fields, but only 'effDate' populates a value, while 'dropDownSelect' remains as a registered field with no value.

**Edit:**

Based off the example, I guess the way to go about this is like:

```
function DropDownSelect(person) {
  return (
    <option key={person} value={person}>{person}</option>
  );
}

export default DropDownSelect;


      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="dropDownSelect">Select an Option</label>
        <Field
          name="dropDownSelect"
          component="select"
          // component={DropDownSelect}
          // people={people}
          className="form-control"
        >
          {people.map(DropDownSelect)}
        </Field>
```

This works for now, though it would be ideal if I could implement this as a completely separate component (as outlined in the initial question), so I can take advantage of lifecycle hooks in the case the field will depend on other fields.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make separate custom component that handles drop down select, I needed to include the 'input' props to connect it to the form reducer:

Custom Component:

```
/**
*
* DropDownSelect
*
*/

import React from 'react';

import styles from './styles.css';

class DropDownSelect extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  renderSelectOptions = (person) => (
    <option key={person} value={person}>{person}</option>
  )

  render() {
    const { input, label } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <label htmlFor={label}>{label}</label> */}
        <select {...input}>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          {this.props.people.map(this.renderSelectOptions)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// function DropDownSelect(person) {
//   return (
//     <option key={person} value={person}>{person}</option>
//   );
// }

DropDownSelect.propTypes = {
  people: React.PropTypes.array,
  input: React.PropTypes.object,
  label: React.PropTypes.string,
};

export default DropDownSelect;
```

Field:

```
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="dropDownSelect">Select an Option</label>
        <Field
          name="dropDownSelect"
          // component="select"
          label="dropDownSelect"
          component={DropDownSelect}
          people={people}
          className="form-control"
        >
          {/* {people.map(DropDownSelect)} */}
        </Field>
      </div>
```

Comment: How do you do custom rendering for errors. e.g. Appending something like this to show there's an error with the input.

`{touched && error && (<div role="alert" className="error">Error!</div>)}`

Comment: How do you disabled the dropdown field in redux from?

Comment: @BharathMb The `disabled` prop is natively supported by HTML and can be dropped in as any other prop. With this example, you could pass in `disabled` as a prop through `Field` and drill it down into the `<select>` tag like:

`<select {...input} disabled={true}>...</select>`